# Custom Submit Action Not Getting Called

Tags: sitecore-forms

Sitecore Version - 9.3

I have created a custom submit action but it is not working. It is not even getting called when I hit with debugger.

**Submit Action Code -**

```
using Sitecore;
using Sitecore.Data;
using Sitecore.Diagnostics;
using Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Models;
using Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Processing;
using Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Processing.Actions;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Sitecore.Analytics;
//using Sitecore.XConnect.Client;
//using Sitecore.XConnect;
//using Sitecore.XConnect.Collection.Model;
using Sitecore.Data.Fields;
using Sitecore.Resources.Media;
using Sitecore.Links.UrlBuilders;
 
 
namespace ProjectName.SitecoreForms.Actions
{
    [CLSCompliant(false)]
    public class SendEmailToCsd : SubmitActionBase<SendEmailActionData>
    {
 
        private ISubmitActionHelper _submitActionHelper;
 
        private IVisitorTokensProvider VisitorTokensProvider { get; }
        private static Guid PortalId
           => Context.Database.GetItem(Context.Site.RootPath).ID.Guid;
 
        public SendEmailToCsd(ISubmitActionData submitActionData) : base(submitActionData)
        {
            VisitorTokensProvider = new VisitorTokensProvider();
        }
 
        public SendEmailToCsd(ISubmitActionData submitActionData,
                              ISubmitActionHelper submitActionHelper,
                              IVisitorTokensProvider visitorTokensProvider) : base(submitActionData)
        {
            _submitActionHelper = submitActionHelper;
            VisitorTokensProvider = visitorTokensProvider;
        }
 
        private ISubmitActionHelper SubmitActionHelper => _submitActionHelper ?? (_submitActionHelper = new SubmitActionHelper());
       /// <summary>
        /// Execute method for custom submit action
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="data"></param>
        /// <param name="formSubmitContext"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        protected override bool Execute(SendEmailActionData data, FormSubmitContext formSubmitContext)
        {
 
            try
            {

 
                //logic goes here
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error("Some error occurred while sending email to CSD ", ex, this);
                return false;
            }
 
        }
 
       
    }
}
```

**Submit Action Item -**

[image]

[image]

Can someone please suggest what I may have missed here?

Comment: Did you select this custom action on your submit button on the form?

Comment: yes let me add a screenshot of that as well.

Comment: @SumitBhatia updated screenshot

Comment: are you getting any error in logs and on browser console? Also when you remove the save data and keep only the custom one. what happens?

Comment: Have you published that submit action item?

Comment: @SumitBhatia No errors in logs, even in the network tab, formbuilder request is giving 200 OK. If I remove Save Data, and keep custom one, then also same results.

Comment: @MarekMusielak yes, I checked in the Web database, custom submit action item is present.

Comment: Did you publish your DLL in debug mode to debug the code? and Also mention Class and assembly name correctly in your item?

Comment: @SumitBhatia Thank you for helping. The assembly name was incorrect. I corrected it now it is working.

Comment: @NewbieHere I have added the possible solutions. If you find them helpful kindly mark the answer as helpful for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per our discussion in chat, Here are the possible solutions to troubleshoot your issue.

- You can check the assembly name in your Sitecore item
- check if it was deployed to your solutions.
- Check if the item is published.
- Examine Sitecore logs for any error messages or exceptions related to your custom submit action. Ensure that the necessary logs are enabled in the Sitecore configuration.
- Use the browser's developer tools to check for any JavaScript errors when submitting the form.
- Inspect network requests to see if there are any issues with data being sent or received.
- Double-check your Sitecore configuration files to ensure that the custom submit action is correctly registered.
- Confirm that the form is configured to use the correct submit action.
- Clear Sitecore and browser caches to ensure that you are not encountering caching-related problems

Hope this helps.